# In French, how do you say colloquially "X hit me right in the feels"?

Tags: expressions, anglais

> This documentary film **hit me right in the feels**, making me bawl like a baby.

This is a colloquial expression that means more or less the same as "X got me emotionally". I'd express this idea in French as:

> Ce film documentaire, ça **m'a profondément touché** / **ému**.

... but I wonder if there are other expressions that fit the tone of "X hit me right in the feels"?

Comment: Me, I was trying to figure out how one says “hit me right in the feels” in English in the first place. :) Apparently using *feels* for *feelings* was exquisitely rare in English up until just a few years ago when it surfaced as hip teenage slang, the sort of thing most of us need subtitles to understand. :)

Comment: Not only hip, but cutesy. Definitely still an evolving expression. Currently hearing things like "The feels!" and crossovers with "all the things": "All the feels!" Incidentally, for this reason it doesn't jive well with the stuffy-sounding "documentary film" or the rest of that sentence structure. Prefer "That movie hit me right in the feels. I was bawling like a baby." (Hopefully these notes are helpful to equivalent-hunters.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak You'd even read "dem feels" on places as 9gag.

Comment: @Rightleg So you would. Though I put in every effort to avoid the place...

Comment: And the official outreach to patrons of the Toronto International Film Festival just sent an email with the subject "All. The. Feels."

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know the English phrase but this might match it:

> *Ce documentaire<sup>1</sup> m'a [pris aux tripes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_aux_tripes).*

<sup>1</sup><sub>*Documentaire* is now used as a substantive when referring to a movie so we usually drop *film*.</sub>

Comment: Interesting. Does it belong to informal register, being more casual than my version? By the way, do you detect any nuance between "toucher" and "emouvoir"?

Comment: Yes, *prendre aux tripes* is less formal than *toucher* and *émouvoir* which are synonymous here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "remuer" or "secouer", that mean the same as "émouvoir", which translate as "move":

> Ce documentaire m'a **secoué**.
>
> Ce documentaire m'a **remué**.

These can be used along with "tripes" (which means "guts"):

> Ça m'a **remué les tripes**.

You could even use "secoué" on its own:

> Après (avoir vu) ce documentaire, j'étais **secoué**.

These days, "choquer" made its come-back, so the following would be pretty much colloquial as well:

> J'étais **choqué**.
> J'ai été **choqué** par ce documentaire.

---

In addition, I'd say it would all become much more colloquial with an adverb:

> Ça m'a **complètement** choqué.
> Ça m'a **carrément** secoué.

Comment: Hi. Is it just me, but "secouer" seems to always carry a negative connotation, like: "The incident ***shook*** her ***up*** quite a bit". As such, saying "ce documentaire m'a secoué" sounds to me as if this documentary film had a negative psychological impact on her. "X hit me right in the feels" is more about 感動 in a positive sense. :) What do you think?

Comment: 感动/感動する do mean "move" or "émouvoir", all in a neutral sense. "Secouer", in this colloquial meaning, does mean the same as "émouvoir". It does not bear any negative meaning, it's just rather strong. Well, you couldn't say "secouer" with a strongly positive feeling, like "secoué par le bonheur", although it could appear somewhat poetic...